# Linux: /dev/null/: Is a directory

Tags: linux, bash

In an attempt to throw away my errors, I am getting this error. `/dev/null/: Is a directory`

What does that mean? and how can I make it so I can throw away my errors like so: `echo "hello" 2>/dev/null/`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Get rid of the trailing slash.

```
echo "hello" 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 4):

If /dev/null is a directory, something is wrong in your Linux system and you need to restore it. You do it with the following bash commands as *root*:

```
mknod /dev/null c 1 2
chmod 666 /dev/null
```

after having removed the `null` directory,